# How to give input to replace() when the string is present in an array

Tags: javascript

I have to replace the special characters in my string with underscore. `replace()` function is used to do it . I know that.

My string is "545123_Claims#Claims#Claims000117".

But the issue is that `replace()` accepts sting as input.

Actually my string is in an array like `filArr= ["545123_Claims#Claims#Claims000117"]`.

So how can I replace the special character in thisstring which is inside an array?

Comment: My string is "`545123_Claims#Claims#Claims000117`". Value?

Comment: you can use regex to replace `string.replace(/[_#]/g,'')`

Comment: `newStr = filArr[0].replace(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You could map the replaced strings by taking a function.

```
const replacementFn = string => string.replace(/xxx/, 'yyy');

filArr = fillArr.map(replacementFn);
```